# Can I use this callback result with Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp, backbone-relational

I hope someone can help me as Ive been trying for well over a week to see if I can use this callback result to populate a Backbone model/Collection.

Specifically, I want to list the Area Name and the AreaGUID - I also want to get the total price from the PriceMatrix.

PriceMatrix aside - I'd even settle for the Area Name and AreaGUID as I would hopefully learn how to traverse this JSON, and make collections from its nested values.

JSON:

```
$esro.GenericCallBack: (
{
"CustomCallback": "getEventDescriptionCallback",
"ErrorDescription": "",
"EvalMe": "",
"HasError": false,
"Result": {
    "__type": "EventItemEntity:#eSRO.Code.JSonEntities",
    "Areas": [
        {
            "Area": {
                "AreaGuid": "9fc8ae7e-2059-4eb6-8c6f-527f3a0ea5fc",
                "AreaMapGuid": "97a511ac-6b36-4223-9a08-5e099ebcd6ee",
                "DefaultSeatingType": 10,
                "GADefaultSettings": {
                    "Capacity": 10000,
                    "PriceLevelGuid": null,
                    "Restrictions": null
                },
                "Name": {
                    "Value": "Balc  Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "NameForReports": {
                    "Value": "Balc  Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "Ordinal": 0,
                "ParentHallGuid": "b4df2722-fe70-4b03-bf9b-4a35286b1330",
                "StandId": null,
                "StandName": null
            },
            "AreaMap": {
                "AreaMapGuid": "97a511ac-6b36-4223-9a08-5e099ebcd6ee",
                "DescriptionLevel": 1,
                "GASettings": null,
                "GateCombinations": null,
                "IncludedInMultipleVersions": false,
                "Name": {
                    "Value": "Balc  Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "NumberOfSeats": 180,
                "ParentAreaGuid": "9fc8ae7e-2059-4eb6-8c6f-527f3a0ea5fc",
                "SeatingType": 20,
                "Sectors": null,
                "Status": 20,
                "TurnstileCombinations": null,
                "PriceLevelIds": [
                    "7ec859f6-2294-4b0f-b57a-9fa120c221a6",
                    "5112ea83-0880-4785-b93c-21e18c7a667b"
                ]
            },
            "Connector": {
                "AreaLevelViewXaml": null,
                "AreaMapGuid": "97a511ac-6b36-4223-9a08-5e099ebcd6ee",
                "BackgroundImageIds": null,
                "BestAvailableReservation": true,
                "HallLevelViewXaml": "<Properties><Width>770</Width><Height>185</Height><X>0</X><Y>0</Y><Angle>0</Angle><Xaml /><AreaLabel /><StageSide /><IfShowLabel /></Properties>",
                "Ordinal": 1,
                "ParentVersionGuid": "b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5",
                "StaticViewXamls": null,
                "ViewFromAreaImageId": null
            },
            "DependencyTags": [
                "AreaMap=97a511ac-6b36-4223-9a08-5e099ebcd6ee",
                "SeatingPlan=0aaa76eb-0b49-4ab7-9ef7-767b8400fb11",
                "Area=9fc8ae7e-2059-4eb6-8c6f-527f3a0ea5fc;SeatingPlan=0aaa76eb-0b49-4ab7-9ef7-767b8400fb11",
                "Show=37f6bcd8-c63c-4967-9982-3c3ae4c204e4",
                "Area=9fc8ae7e-2059-4eb6-8c6f-527f3a0ea5fc;Show=37f6bcd8-c63c-4967-9982-3c3ae4c204e4",
                "HallVersion=b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5",
                "Area=9fc8ae7e-2059-4eb6-8c6f-527f3a0ea5fc;HallVersion=b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5"
            ],
            "ImageUris": []
        },
        {
            "Area": {
                "AreaGuid": "063b1dad-e789-4857-852f-5e733fa84865",
                "AreaMapGuid": "6c716990-9686-4304-a015-4db450f2fbd5",
                "DefaultSeatingType": 10,
                "GADefaultSettings": {
                    "Capacity": 1078,
                    "PriceLevelGuid": null,
                    "Restrictions": null
                },
                "Name": {
                    "Value": "ORCH Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "NameForReports": {
                    "Value": "ORCH Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "Ordinal": 0,
                "ParentHallGuid": "b4df2722-fe70-4b03-bf9b-4a35286b1330",
                "StandId": null,
                "StandName": null
            },
            "AreaMap": {
                "AreaMapGuid": "6c716990-9686-4304-a015-4db450f2fbd5",
                "DescriptionLevel": 1,
                "GASettings": null,
                "GateCombinations": null,
                "IncludedInMultipleVersions": false,
                "Name": {
                    "Value": "ORCH Fest 2013 Murmur"
                },
                "NumberOfSeats": 425,
                "ParentAreaGuid": "063b1dad-e789-4857-852f-5e733fa84865",
                "SeatingType": 20,
                "Sectors": null,
                "Status": 20,
                "TurnstileCombinations": null,
                "PriceLevelIds": [
                    "7ec859f6-2294-4b0f-b57a-9fa120c221a6",
                    "5c9fa97b-c47c-463a-8da4-78956a241e5e",
                    "5112ea83-0880-4785-b93c-21e18c7a667b",
                    "01b28b26-b09c-46c3-b75a-02331c1231f9",
                    "e717cf91-986d-486d-b533-1309123fbf78"
                ]
            },
            "Connector": {
                "AreaLevelViewXaml": null,
                "AreaMapGuid": "6c716990-9686-4304-a015-4db450f2fbd5",
                "BackgroundImageIds": null,
                "BestAvailableReservation": true,
                "HallLevelViewXaml": "<Properties><Width>770</Width><Height>185</Height><X>0</X><Y>195</Y><Angle>0</Angle><Xaml /><AreaLabel /><StageSide /><IfShowLabel /></Properties>",
                "Ordinal": 2,
                "ParentVersionGuid": "b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5",
                "StaticViewXamls": null,
                "ViewFromAreaImageId": null
            },
            "DependencyTags": [
                "AreaMap=6c716990-9686-4304-a015-4db450f2fbd5",
                "SeatingPlan=0aaa76eb-0b49-4ab7-9ef7-767b8400fb11",
                "Area=063b1dad-e789-4857-852f-5e733fa84865;SeatingPlan=0aaa76eb-0b49-4ab7-9ef7-767b8400fb11",
                "Show=37f6bcd8-c63c-4967-9982-3c3ae4c204e4",
                "Area=063b1dad-e789-4857-852f-5e733fa84865;Show=37f6bcd8-c63c-4967-9982-3c3ae4c204e4",
                "HallVersion=b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5",
                "Area=063b1dad-e789-4857-852f-5e733fa84865;HallVersion=b0352f6b-056d-4577-b3c1-c0ae8773bbb5"
            ],
            "ImageUris": []
        }
    ],
    "Id": "0aaa76eb-0b49-4ab7-9ef7-767b8400fb11",
    "Pricing": {
        "PriceLevelAxis": [
            {
                "key": "7ec859f6-2294-4b0f-b57a-9fa120c221a6",
                "value": "C Price"
            },
            {
                "key": "5112ea83-0880-4785-b93c-21e18c7a667b",
                "value": "B Price"
            },
            {
                "key": "5c9fa97b-c47c-463a-8da4-78956a241e5e",
                "value": "W/C  Wheel chair**  C Price"
            },
            {
                "key": "01b28b26-b09c-46c3-b75a-02331c1231f9",
                "value": "W/C  Wheel chair**  B Price"
            },
            {
                "key": "e717cf91-986d-486d-b533-1309123fbf78",
                "value": "A Price"
            }
        ],
        "PriceMatrix": [
            [
                {
                    "ListPrice": "<Money amount=\"25\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>",
                    "PriceModifiers": null,
                    "TotalPrice": "<Money amount=\"25\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>"
                },
                {
                    "ListPrice": "<Money amount=\"40\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>",
                    "PriceModifiers": null,
                    "TotalPrice": "<Money amount=\"40\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>"
                },
                {
                    "ListPrice": "<Money amount=\"25\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>",
                    "PriceModifiers": null,
                    "TotalPrice": "<Money amount=\"25\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>"
                },
                {
                    "ListPrice": "<Money amount=\"40\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>",
                    "PriceModifiers": null,
                    "TotalPrice": "<Money amount=\"40\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>"
                },
                {
                    "ListPrice": "<Money amount=\"55\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>",
                    "PriceModifiers": null,
                    "TotalPrice": "<Money amount=\"55\" currencyCode=\"\" xmlns=\"http://foundation.toptix.com/2007\"/>"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "PriceModifierDescriptions": [],
        "PriceTypeAxis": [
            {
                "key": "5ea4520c-d647-4a8c-b392-3f52910396d4",
                "value": "FULL"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SeatingTypeEnum": [
        {
            "key": "GA",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "key": "BA",
            "value": 20
        }
    ],
    "ShowName": "Murmurs"
}
```

}
)

Model and Collection currently:

```
Entities.Area = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
Id: '',
  AreaGuid:'',
  AreaMapGuid: '',
  AreaNameValue: '',
  DefaultSeatingType: '',
  PriceLevelIds: '',
  MinPriceLevelIds: '',
  MaxPriceLevelIds: '',
  SeatingPlan: '',
  BestAvailableReservation: '',
  PriceLevelAxis: '',
  PriceMatrix: '',
  ShowName: '',
  FacilityFee: '',
  ServiceFee : '',
  SeatPriceTotal : ''
```

Collection:

```
Entities.AreaCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
      this.on('all', function(e) { console.log("Area event: " +e); });
  },
  url: "./murmurs.json",

model: Entities.Area,
    parse : function(response){
   return response.Result;  
  }
});
```

Please help if you can - and thanks!

Comment: Can you also share your model and collection definitions?

Comment: i added thoise into the original post - thanks bvoleti

Answer (score 0):

you can have a straightforward hierarchical design like this  ...

```
var RootModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
default:
    {
        "CustomCallback": "",
        "ErrorDescription": "",
        "EvalMe": "",
        "HasError": false,
        "Result": null
    }
});

var ResultModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
default:
    {
        "__type": "",
        "Areas": []
    }
});

var AreaCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: areaDetailsModel
});

var AreaDetailsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
default:
    {
        "Area": null,
        "AreaMap": null,
        "Connector": null
    }
});

var AreaModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
default:
    {
        "AreaGuid": "",
        "AreaMapGuid": "",
        "DefaultSeatingType": 0,
        "GADefaultSettings": null,
        "Name": "",
        "NameForReports": "",
        "Ordinal": 0,
        "ParentHallGuid": "",
        "StandId": null,
        "StandName": null
    }
});

var AreaMapModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
default:
    {
        "AreaMapGuid": "",
        "DescriptionLevel": "",
        "GASettings": null,
        "GateCombinations": null,
        "IncludedInMultipleVersions": false,
        "Name": "",
        "NumberOfSeats": 0,
        "ParentAreaGuid": "",
        "SeatingType": 0,
        "Sectors": null,
        "Status": 0,
        "TurnstileCombinations": null,
        "PriceLevelIds": []
    }
});
```

....

Then, you can assign your callback result to the rootModel.

```
var rootModel= new RootModel("your callback to JSON");

var resultModel = new ResultModel(rootModel.get("Result"));

var areas = new AreaCollection(resultModel.get("Areas"));

var areaDetail = areas.at(0);

var area = new AreaModel(areadetail.get("area");
```

...

Comment: nice - thanks for the time it took to put this up as a possible answer for me. Ill go check it out now and post.

Comment: so the last line there:    **var area = new AreaModel(areadetail.get("area"));**   doesnt recognize areadetail

Comment: feels sooo close - but changing to **areaDetail** says **TypeError: areaDetail is undefined
 

var area = new AreaModel(areaDetail.get("Area"));**

Comment: AreaCollection is a collection of AreaDetail ... I assume, that could be a problem ...

AreaDetail aggregates "Area", "AreaMap" and on on ... 

..based on your original callback result

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but this may work.

```
var area_detail_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    AreaGuid: null,
    AreaMapGuid: null
  }
});

var area_map_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    AreaMapGuid: null,
    DescriptionLevel: null
  }
});

var area_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    Area: new area_detail_model(),
    AreaMap: new area_map_model(),
    Connector: [] // can declare a model for connector also
    DependencyTags: [] // when using an array we can write bb_obj.get('Attr').ArrayItemName
  },
  parse : function(response){
    // at this point only area models exist, i.e from area collection each area model
    // is passed to this parse method
    response.Area =  new area_model(response.Area);
    response.AreaModel =  new area_map_model(response.AreaModel);
    return response;
  }
});

var area_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: area_model,
  url: '/Areas',
  parse : function(response){
    return response; // place a break point and check out the contents of response
  }
});

var result_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
     Areas: new area_collection(),
     Id: null,
     Pricing: null,
  },
  url: '/GetResults',
  parse : function(response){
    response.Result.Areas = new area_collection(response.Result.Areas);
    return response.Result; // this will return only the Result section from your JSON
  }
});

var result_obj = new result_model();
result_obj.fetch();
```

So when the response is fetched then the result_model parse function will only pick Result from JSON and then we create a collection out the areas and the corresponding parse for each collection and method will be called in order. Let me know if it works.